# Dynamic Select query In Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle10g

I want to write a stored procedure in Oracle passing dynamic value as below:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE DETAILDISCDATA2
(
  USERTYPE IN VARCHAR2,
  BID IN NUMBER,
  SORT_COLUMN IN VARCHAR2,
  SORT_ORDER IN VARCHAR2,
  catCur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS 
COUNTRY_CODE VARCHAR2(10) := 'USA';

v_sql varchar2(1000);
BEGIN

v_sql := 'SELECT bd.*, BD.ATS_ITEM_LIST_PRICE_UNIT as UNIT_NORMAL_NET, BD.ITEM_LIST_PRICE_TOTAL as NORMAL_NET '
' FROM bdetail BD '
' LEFT OUTER JOIN CATALOG_SCH_DISC DD '
' ON BD.MAT_NR       = DD.PRODUCT_NO '
' AND DD.COUNTRY_CODE= :a ';
' AND BD.Id = :b  order by :c :d';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql using COUNTRY_CODE, BID ,SORT_COLUMN,SORT_ORDER;

END DETAILDISCDATA2;
```

When I execute this stored procedure, it displays output with no data, but if I run same query with static value gives proper output

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this procedure will not "display" anything. It won't even execute the SELECT statement if there is no INTO or BULK COLLECT INTO clause

Comment: I want to retrive records dynmically with dynamic sorting column and sorting order

Comment: Thanks for feedback Marcin, can you please give me updated query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1201):

> If *dynamic_sql_statement* is a SELECT statement, and you omit both *into_clause* and *bulk_collect_into_clause*, then execute_immediate_statement never executes.

You don't have an `into` clause as part of your `execute immediate`.

However, fromthe OUT parameter, it looks like what you really want is to open the ref cursor for that query:

```
OPEN catCur FOR v_sql using COUNTRY_CODE, BID ,SORT_COLUMN,SORT_ORDER;
```

You can't specify column names in the `order_by` with bind variables though. You'd need to concatenate those, so it would be:

```
v_sql := 'SELECT bd.*, BD.ATS_ITEM_LIST_PRICE_UNIT as UNIT_NORMAL_NET, '
|| ' BD.ITEM_LIST_PRICE_TOTAL as NORMAL_NET '
|| ' FROM bdetail BD '
|| ' LEFT OUTER JOIN CATALOG_SCH_DISC DD '
|| ' ON BD.MAT_NR       = DD.PRODUCT_NO '
|| ' AND DD.COUNTRY_CODE= :a '
|| ' AND BD.Id = :b '
|| ' order by ' || SORT_COLUMN || ' ' || SORT_ORDER;

OPEN catCur FOR v_sql using COUNTRY_CODE, BID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,

1) I think you want to use your catCur parameter like this:

```
open catCur for 'SELECT ....';
```

and then pass the parameter somewhere else - where you want to use it

2) This part: "... order by :c :d" won't work. You cannot pass column names as variables. You will have to build your statement with static names of columns.

3) Your execute immediate will do nothing in this form. See [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317):

> If dynamic_sql_statement is a SELECT statement, and you omit both
>   into_clause and bulk_collect_into_clause, then
>   execute_immediate_statement never executes. For example, this
>   statement never increments the sequence: